# IntelliJ uses more memory than allocated

Tags: intellij-idea

My `IntelliJ` goes unbearably slow, so I was fiddling with memory settings. If you select Help -> Change Memory Settings, you can set the max heap size for `IntelliJ`. But even after restarting, then running Mac's Activity Monitor, I see it using `5.5GB` even though I set the heap to `4092MB`.

It's using `1.5GB` more than allocated for heap. That's *a lot* of memory for `permgen` + stack, don't you think? Or, could it be that this memory setting actually doesn't have any effect on the program?

Answer (score 1):

It's the virtual memory you see, it may also include memory mapped files and many other things occupied by the JVM internals, plus the native libraries for a dozen of Apple frameworks loaded into the process. There is nothing to worry about unless you get OOM or IDE becomes slow.

If it happens, [refer to the KB documents](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241235) and [report the issues to YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA) with the CPU/Memory snapshots.